# How to add listener to Application Editor in the Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am writing a Eclipse RCP Plug-in for displaying the properties of objects displayed in application editor.
My plug-in extends PageBookView. Every time, i select a new object is opened on the  ApplicationEditor(which is Canvas widget),i create a new page & save the old page.

ApplicationEditor extends EditorPart. It fires propertyChange events when the objects (on the active editor changes).  All i want is to add listener  to applicationEditor. When the required event fires, i have to update my page.

Let me put it in a simmple way.

```
    public Class MyPage implements IPage implements **WHICH_LISTENER**
    {

    public MyPage(ApplicationEditor editor)
    {

    this.addPropertyChangeListener(editor); 

    }
  . . . . . . 

}
```

***Which Listener should i implement to refresh the page by propertyChange().***?

PS: Thanks in advance for your precious advices. Feel free to question me for further  clarity in the Question! I cannot change the editor design or code, as i am trying to contribute to an open source project [OpenVXML](http://www.eclipse.org/vtp/).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of notifying UI-Elements is not optimal. Your UI-Elements should register listeners to the objects which are changing. The question which listener to implement to the editor depends on which object the editor is listen to. In your case the PageBookView needs a reference to ApplicationEditor to register itself, which is not good, because 1. the PageBookView has an unneccessary dependency to the editor and 2) the editor is not responsible for propagating changes, but the object itself. I would do the following.

Your Editor:

```
public class MyEditor extends EditorPart implements PropertyChangeListener

public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) {
// Getting the input and setting it to the editor
this.object = input.getObject();
// add PropertyChangeListener
this.object.addPropertyChangeListener(this)
}

public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvents) {
 // some element of the model has changed. Perform here the UI things to react properly on the change.
}
}
```

The same thing needs to be done on your pageBook.

```
public class MyPropertyView extends PageBook implements PropertyChangeListener{

initModel() {
// you have to pass the model from the editor to the depending pageBook.
this.model = getModelFromEditor()
this.object.addPropertyChangeListener(this)

}
  public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvents) {
     // some element of the model has changed. Perform here the UI things to react properly on the change.
    }
}
```

As you can see both UI Elements are reacting directly to the changes in the model.

Another way of displaying objects in an editor is to use ProperyViews, for an further description see http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html

A time ago, I've written a simple example for all this notification stuff in Eclipse see [here](http://www.richclient2.de/2006_08_22/using-the-mvc-pattern-in-eclipse-applications/).

HTH Tom